# Need to create excel charts with static scale

Tags: excel

I need to make a chart where the scale is static, so if one chart had a series with a max value of 10 units and another had a max value of only two, my customer would like to see both charts display as if they were on the same scale.  They want a chart for every month and static scales on each month.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Charts can be made static as in the diagrams below:

[image]

[image]